Summation of three terms with certain condition

To solve this problem there is one condition $1\le i<j\le k\le 20$
Solving individually is a cumbersome process hence trying to use formula
Using the equation $(x+x^2+x^3+..+x^{10}+2(x^{11}+x^{12}+x^{13}+...+x^{20}))$
$(x+x^2+x^3+..+x^{10})(1+2x^{10})$
But cannot proceed from here

Well, I believe you can distribute the $1 \leq i \leq j \leq k \leq 20 $ over the 3 sums and from there on split it. Else how are you computing $\sum a_i a_j a_k$?

Well...the product is one of $1,2,4,8$.  I suggest counting the triples that give rise to each of those.

And, for clarity, is your sum correct as written?  You are currently requiring $i<j$ but you allow $j≤k$, so $a_1a_1a_2$ is not allowed but $a_1a_2a_2$ is.  Is that what you intended?

Yes I crossed checked it

Note:
After the fact, I saw that lulu's comment anticipated my approach.
Shortcut:
If $~a_i~$ always equaled $~1,~$ which it does not, then you would have the immediate answer of $~\displaystyle \binom{20}{3}.~$
Given the specification, you simply need to partition the $~\displaystyle \binom{20}{3}~$ ordered triplets into the $~4~$ subsets depending on $~k~$ the number of components of the corresponding ordered triples that are $~\geq 11.~$
Here $~k \in \{0,1,2,3\}.~$
Letting $~f(k)~$ denote the corresponding number of triplets, then the desired computation is
$$\left[ ~1 \times f(0) ~\right] + 
\left[ ~2 \times f(1) ~\right] + 
\left[ ~4 \times f(2) ~\right] + 
\left[ ~8 \times f(3) ~\right]. \tag1 $$
So, the entire problem reduces to computing $~f(0), ~f(1), ~f(2), ~f(3).$
Further, by considerations of symmetry, $~f(0) = f(4),~$ and $~f(1) = f(2).$
Then,
$$f(0) = \binom{10}{3}, ~~f(1) = \binom{10}{1} \times \binom{10}{2}.$$
